# Element in com.google.gwt.user.client has been deprecated

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I migrated to gwt 2.8.1 and I am using gxt 2.2.5

I have this line of code that is causing the wanrning mentionned on the title

```
El el = new El((Element) grid.getView().getRow(Model))
```

getRow() return type is `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element`

El is  `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.core.EL` and parameter type is `com.google.gwt.user.client.Element`.

The issue is that `com.google.gwt.user.client.Element` was deprecated and replaced by `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element`.

Will the code will still be working?

Is there a workaround to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 3):

The deprecated `Element` extends the not-deprecated `Element`, so the code is still working, but you have many warnings in your files.

Answer (score 0):

After searching I found that the `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.core.El` class has two constructors, so I may be using this method:

```
El el = new El(gridView().gerRow(model).getString))
```

is it reliable?